# Extjs + Spring + JPA + HIbernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, extjs

We have Web application Extjs, Spring3.0, JPA, Hibernate. I have search page with single entity which working fine but yesterday I have added  @manytoone in User Entity and application stop working. Extjs start throwing exception. when i try to debug I found out problem beacuase of @manytoOne relationship. Can any one please give me hint ?

```
@Controller
public class BusinessCalsController  {

        @Autowired
        private BusinessCalService businessCalService;

        public void setBusinessCalService(BusinessCalService businessCalService) {
            this.businessCalService = businessCalService;
        }

       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       @RequestMapping(value="/businessCalView.do",method=RequestMethod.GET)
       public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> view(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            try{
                String strStart = request.getParameter("start"); //start index
                String strLimit = request.getParameter("limit"); //limit record num
                String strSort = request.getParameter("sort"); //desc or asc
                String strDir = request.getParameter("dir"); //property for sort
                Map businessCal = (Map)businessCalService.getBusinessCalList(strStart, strLimit, strSort, strDir);
                Map modelMap = getJSONMap((List<BusinessCal>) businessCal.get("resultSet"));
                return modelMap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return getModelMapError("Error retrieving Machine from database.");
            }
            }


        /**
         * Generates modelMap to return in the modelAndView
         * @param contacts
         * @return
         */
        private Map<String,Object> getJSONMap(List<BusinessCal> businessCal){

            Map<String,Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);
            modelMap.put("total", businessCal.size());
            modelMap.put("data", businessCal);
            modelMap.put("success", true);
            return modelMap;
        }

        /**
         * Generates modelMap to return in the modelAndView in case
         * of exception
         * @param msg message
         * @return
         */
        private Map<String,Object> getModelMapError(String msg){

            Map<String,Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String,Object>(2);
            modelMap.put("message", msg);
            modelMap.put("success", false);
            return modelMap;
        }   
}

@Service
public class BusinessCalService {
    @Autowired
    private BusinessCalDAO businessCalDAO;
    private BusinessCalJsonUtil util;

    /**
     * Get all contacts
     * @return
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Object getBusinessCalList(String strStart,String strLimit,String strSort, String strDir){
        return businessCalDAO.searchBusinessCal(strStart, strLimit, strSort, strDir);
    }

    /**
     * @return the userCalDAO
     */
    public BusinessCalDAO getBusinessCalDAO() {
        return businessCalDAO;
    }

    /**
     * @param userCalDAO the userCalDAO to set
     */
    @Autowired
    public void setBusinessCalDAO(BusinessCalDAO businessCalDAO) {
        this.businessCalDAO = businessCalDAO;
    }   

    /**
     * Spring use - DI
     * @param util
     */
    @Autowired
    public void setJsonUtil(BusinessCalJsonUtil util) {
        this.util = util;
    }
}

@Repository
public class BusinessCalDAO {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    private boolean flag;

    /**
     * @return the hibernateTemplate
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate){  
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Get List of UsersCals from database
     * @return list of all contacts
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object searchBusinessCal(String strStart,String strLimit,String strSort, String strDir) {
        PageHibernate newPage = null;
        BusinessCal obj = new BusinessCal();
        newPage = new PageHibernate("from BusinessCal", (strStart != null &&  !strStart.equals("null")) ? Integer.parseInt(strStart) : 0 , (strLimit != null &&  !strLimit.equals("null")) ? Integer.parseInt(strLimit) : 0 ,obj.getClass());
        return hibernateTemplate.execute(newPage);
    }
}


 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="SP_BU_CALS",schema ="TAX_STG") 
public class BusinessCal implements Serializable{

    private BULookUp  objBULookUp;
    private Integer   intID;
    private String    strBussUnitId;

    /**
     * @return the intID
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FEED_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="FEED_SEQ", sequenceName = "TAX_FEED.FEED_SEQ")     
    public Integer getIntID() {
        return intID;
    }
    /**
     * @param intID the intID to set
     */
    public void setIntID(Integer intID) {
        this.intID = intID;
    }
    /**
     * @return the strBusinessUnitId
     */
    @Column(name="BU_ID")
    public String getStrBussUnitId() {
        return strBussUnitId;
    }
    /**
     * @param strBusinessUnitId the strBusinessUnitId to set
     */
    public void setStrBussUnitId(String strBussUnitId) {
        this.strBussUnitId = strBussUnitId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the objBULookUp
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BU_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public BULookUp getObjBULookUp() {
        return objBULookUp;
    }
    /**
     * @param objBULookUp the objBULookUp to set
     */
    public void setObjBULookUp(BULookUp objBULookUp) {
        this.objBULookUp = objBULookUp;
    }
}
```

Problem start arice when i have added BULookUp objBULookUp in BusinessCal model. 
Let me add code for BULookUp as well as code for extjs file.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="SP_BU_LKUP",schema ="TAX_STG") 
public class BULookUp implements Serializable{

    private String  strBusinessUnitID;
    private String  strBusinessUnitDescription;
    private String  strCBDCode;
    private Integer intActive;

    /**
     * @return the strBusinessUnitID
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name="BU_ID")
    public String getStrBusinessUnitID() {
        return strBusinessUnitID;
    }
    /**
     * @param strBusinessUnitID the strBusinessUnitID to set
     */
    public void setStrBusinessUnitID(String strBusinessUnitID) {
        this.strBusinessUnitID = strBusinessUnitID;
    }
    /**
     * @return the strBusinessUnitDescription
     */
    @Column(name="BU_DESCR")
    public String getStrBusinessUnitDescription() {
        return strBusinessUnitDescription;
    }
    /**
     * @param strBusinessUnitDescription the strBusinessUnitDescription to set
     */
    public void setStrBusinessUnitDescription(String strBusinessUnitDescription) {
        this.strBusinessUnitDescription = strBusinessUnitDescription;
    }
    /**
     * @return the strCBDCode
     */
    @Column(name="CBD")
    public String getStrCBDCode() {
        return strCBDCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param strCBDCode the strCBDCode to set
     */
    public void setStrCBDCode(String strCBDCode) {
        this.strCBDCode = strCBDCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the intActive
     */
    @Column(name="ACTIVE")
    public Integer getIntActive() {
        return intActive;
    }
    /**
     * @param intActive the intActive to set
     */
    public void setIntActive(Integer intActive) {
        this.intActive = intActive;
    }
}
```

Please find below code for extjs

```
app = function() {

       var createForm;
       var updateForm;
       var ds;
       var dataGrid;
       var menu;
       var updateMenuItem;
       var createMenuItem;
       var readMenuItem;
       var deleteMenuItem;
       var tb;
       var sm;
       var userRecord;
       var reader;
       var writer;
       var proxy;
       var pagetbUsers;

       var getContext = function() {  

            var base = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];  
            if (base && base.href && (base.href.length > 0)) {  
                base = base.href;  
            } else {  
                base = document.URL;  
            }  
            return base.substr(0, base.indexOf("/", base.indexOf("/", base.indexOf("//") + 2) + 1));  
        };  

        var onRowClick = function(SelectionModel,rowIndex,record)  {
            onUpdateClick()
        }       
        return {
            init:function() {

            businessCalRecord = Ext.data.Record.create([
                    {name: 'intID', type: 'int'},
                    {name: 'strBussUnitId',   type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'intCalCount', type: 'int'},
                    {name: 'strCalType',type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'strCalDescription', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'strCountType', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'strCalStart', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'strCalEnd', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'strCreatedBy', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'tmpCreatedDate', type: 'date'},
                    {name: 'strActive', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'tmpInActiveDate', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'strCalID', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'objBULookUp.strBusinessUnitID', type: 'string'} 
                ]);

            // The new DataWriter component.
            writer = new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
                encode: true,
                writeAllFields: true
            });

            // The new DataReader component.
            reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                totalProperty: 'total',
                successProperty: 'success',
                idProperty: 'intID',
                root: 'data',
                messageProperty: 'message'  // <-- New "messageProperty" meta-data
            }, 
            businessCalRecord);

            proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy(new Ext.data.Connection({
                api: {read:   {url:'businessCalView.do',  method: 'GET'}},
                autoAbort: true
            }));

            proxy.addListener('exception', function(proxy, options, response, error, res) {
                alert(error);
                alert("proxy.addListener");
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title: 'ERROR',
                    msg: res.message,
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }); 

            proxy.on({
                "loadexception": function(proxy, options, response, error) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                    alert("proxy.on");
                    alert(response.status);
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            });

            // Typical Store collecting the Proxy, Reader and Writer together.
            ds = new Ext.data.Store({
                proxy: proxy,
                reader: reader,
                writer: writer,  // <-- plug a DataWriter into the store just as you would a Reader
                autoSave: false // <-- false would delay executing create, update, destroy requests until specifically told to do so with some [save] buton.
            });

            //read the data from simple array
            //ds.load();
            ds.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: 5} }); 

            var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
                 {header: "id", dataIndex: 'intID',hidden: true},
                 {header: "Bussiness Unit Id",dataIndex: 'objBULookUp.strBusinessUnitDescription',sortable: true},
                 {header: "Cal Count", width:80, dataIndex: 'intCalCount', sortable: true},
                 {header: "Cal Type", width: 100, dataIndex: 'strCalType', sortable: true},
                 {header: "Cal Description", width: 180, dataIndex: 'strCalDescription', sortable: true},
                 {header: "Count Type", width: 100, dataIndex: 'strCountType', sortable: true},
                 {header: "Cal Start", width: 100, dataIndex: 'strCalStart', sortable: true},
                 {header: "Cal End", width: 100, dataIndex: 'strCalEnd', sortable: true},
                 {header: "Cal ID", width: 100, dataIndex: 'strCalID', sortable: true}
            ]); 

            sm = new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:'true'});
            sm.addListener('rowselect',onRowClick,this);

            var PagingBar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                pageSize: 5,
                store: ds,
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
                emptyMsg: 'No insurers to display'
            });

            dataGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({applyTo:'readPanel', frame: true,
                ds:ds,
                cm:cm,
                sm:sm,
                bbar: PagingBar,
                title:'Search Page of Business Cal',    
                width: 910,
                height: 195
            });         

        };
}();
```

But when i remove @manytoOne same code working fine.

Appreciate your efforts to look in to my problem.

Variable strBussUnitId is column in BusinessCal model belongs to BULookUp model. BULookUp model is just master data table to store and BusinessCal using that master table data through strBussUnitId.

Noow on front end where we using extjs I can’t show  strBussUnitId which is number I need to shoe corresponding strBusinessUnitDescription for strBussUnitId. For that I created  @manytoOne in BusinessCal model with BULookUp model.

Problem start arise when I have added @manytoOne in BusinessCal model.

Comment: Post your code and the stacktrace or any error that you get.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail before anyone would be able to help you. Show us your entity class (with JPA annotations) and exception stack trace to start.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what exception you're getting or where it's coming from, I'd guess that you're having problems related to Hibernate proxies used for lazy initialization. Either you're getting LazyInitializationExceptions, for which you should apply the [open session in view pattern](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView), or else you're having a problem marshalling the Hibernate proxies to send back to the browser because they're not marshallable by your framework, in which case you'll need to remove the proxies from the object graph in some way, perhaps using an assembly layer of some kind.